# Why do women observe Holika vrata?

Tags: women, festivals, vrata

Holika was Hiranyakashipu's sister and tried to kill Prahlad. Then, why do women observe holika vrata and worship holika wood before lightning fire in it?

Note: Poornima also falls on the Holi day but women observe vrata for Holika along with monthly Poornima vrata.

Comment: As far as I know, my mother used to worship before lightning the wood. But She used to worship Prahalad (Great Bhakta of Vishnu) not Holika. Also I have never hard of Holika fasting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NARADA-PURANA: PART 4: CHAPTER ONE HUNDRED AND TWENTYFOUR: Exposition of Vratas to be observed on the Full Moon and the New Moon days](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12976/page/n203/mode/1up) advocates Holika worship:

> 76b-78. The holy rite of Holika-worship is to be observed on the full moon day in the month of Phalguna. The devotee collects all types of wood and cow-dung cakes. After duly kindling fire therein, by means of extensive Mantras destructive of Raksasas, the devotee repeats this Mantra—
>
> **असृक्पाभयसंत्रस्तै: कृता त्वं होलि बालिशै:**
>
> **अतस्त्वां पूजयिष्यामि भूते भूतिप्रदा भव:॥**
>
> "**O Holi, you have 
>   been made by people of childish traits who are afraid of blood sucking Ogresses. Hence I shall worship you. Be the bestower of prosperity on the living beings.**”
>
> 79. By repeating this Mantra, more and more wood is 
>       thrown in and the fire is made brighter. The devotees go round 
>       it and carry on the festivities with songs and instrumental 
>       music.
>
> 80-81. (There are two opinions about the burning of 
>   Holika).* (one opinion) : This ogress Holika was a terror to 
>   Prahlada. Hence, people burn her with wood to the 
>   accompaniment of songs and instrumental music. This is the 
>   burning of the Samvatsara (year). In the opinion of others, 
>   it is the burning of Kama. Thus O leading Brahmana, you 
>   shall know that there are many traditions in the world.

Comment: Did you know the Holi coloured powders are supposed to represent the ashes of Kamadeva? :). Sorry for upvoting 2-3 at the same time. Hope they don’t get deleted.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks @Archit